# nginx with php5-fpm, maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: php, time, execution

In php.ini I have set "max_execution_time = 1200", phpinfo() confirms that, but my script stops after 300 seconds with message:

"PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded"

Nginx fastcgi_read_timeout is also set to 1200, however I think its more php issue. How to fix that problem?

edit:

It was CodeIgniter framework - it was setting max_execution_time to 300. Thank you for help. :)

Comment: If you `echo ini_get('max_execution_time');` from within the script does it output 300 or 1200? I'm just wondering if for some reason your script is using another ini file or no ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you didn't use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your PHP code.